# Javascript Link Name from another "data" column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I would like to make the name of the link clickable to the correct link. Right now its pulling from an API, where I can add or remove new links in a MySQL database.

So right now, its:
[image: Please see image]

Initial code below:

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link').DataTable( 

    {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "api/links",
        },
        "columns": [

            { "data": "Link" },
            { "data": "Description" },
            { "data": "URL", "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                return '<a id="Link" href="'+data+'" target="_blank">Click!</a>';}},
                    ]
        } 

     );




} );
</script>
```

```html
     <h3> Useful Links (WIP)</h3>
     <table id="link" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>URL</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>

                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th> 
                <th>URL</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Please provide example data to your datatables call so that the snippet works instead of throwing an error since the ajax call fails.

Comment: Your question is now very clear, but you see, someone already had time to downvote my answer to your previously unclear question. and that does not make me happy. your question is making me lose points because you couldnt post something clear to start with. Please remember that this comunity is very harsh towards my points, even though it is your question and im trying to help you, i suffered from your lack of a proper explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Changed portion of code. Added `title` in function, and in the `<a href` added `'+title["Link"]+'`

```
   { "data": "URL", "render": function ( data, type, title, row, meta ) {
        return '<a href="'+data+'" target="_blank">'+title["Link"]+'</a>';}},
```